# Eloquent way to add to model several external fields from same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I do not know how to properly ask the question without showing you some code (the only TL;DR I could think of was the title), so let me begin:

(Please note that my question is not about localization but how to do what I intended to do with Eloquent and this is the simplest code I thought of to explain it.)

On a Laravel project, MySQL database. I do have a table, literals. Next is literals' migration up function :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create("literals", function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("literal_id");
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("language_id");
        $table->string("literal", 1024)->comment("Localized text.");
        $table->unique(["literal_id", "language_id"], "UK_LANGUAGE_ID");
    });
}
```

Literal model:

```
class Literal extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Literal will be used by several models, as its function is to retrieve localized texts depending on current language selected. This is where I am having trouble, as I don't know how to add functions for the other models.

Let's add a model, Example. Example migration up function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('examples', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger("text_literal_id")->default(0);
        $table->foreign("text_literal_id")
                ->references("literal_id")
                ->on("literals");

        $table->unsignedBigInteger("description_literal_id")->default(0);
        $table->foreign("description_literal_id")
                ->references("literal_id")
                ->on("literals");
    });
}
```

And its model:

```
class Example extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ["text_literal_id", "description_literal_id"];

    public function literalText()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Literal::class, "literal_id", "literal_text_id");
    }

    public function literalDescription()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Literal::class, "literal_id", "literal_description_id");
    }

}
```

As there are more than one foreign keys referring the same table I don't know what functions to add on Literal model to set relations right. Let's add some final code (at web.php) to show what I want to do.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    
    if (count(Example::all()) == 0) {
        Example::create(["text_literal_id" => 2, "description_literal_id" => 3]);
    }

    // This query retrieves the fields I need, which should be Example's fields:
    // SELECT
    //     e.id id,
    //     l1.literal text,
    //     l2.literal description
    // from test.examples e 
    // left join (
    //     select literal_id, literal from literals where language_id = 2
    // ) l1 on l1.literal_id = e.text_literal_id
    // left join (
    //     select literal_id, literal from literals where language_id = 2
    // ) l2 on l2.literal_id = e.description_literal_id
    // where e.id = 1;    

    $example = Example::find(1);

    print($example->literalText->literal . "<br>");
    // the above line should return below line's output:
    print(Literal::where("literal_id", 2)->first()->literal . "<br>");

    print($example->literalDescription->literal . "<br>");
    // the above line should return below line's output:
    print(Literal::where("literal_id", 3)->first()->literal . "<br>");

});
```

For this example literals' table contains 4 rows:

```
INSERT INTO test.literals (literal_id,language_id,literal) VALUES
(2,1,'text language 1'),
(2,2,'text language 2'),
(3,1,'description language 1'),
(3,2,'description language 2'),
```

At last, my question is: is it possible to do in an Eloquent way, that $literal->exampleX->literal gets the field? As the code is now, $literal->exampleX is null. Probably because Literal model has the Example relation functions missing, but I searched, I looked at the documentation, watched videos and tutorilas and tried everything I could think of, but I really don't know how to do them. Right now I am retrieving fields manually (Literal::where... lines, which well, get the job done but adds some code smell) but I suppose there's a right Eloquent way of doing this.

Thank you all for your time and wisdom.

NOTE: edited to make it even more concise as requested

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is quite the minimal reproducible example. If you want it slimmer I'll get rid of the scope and one of the three fields, leaving only two of them. Can't cut more than that as this code was created in order to explain my problem and it has no sense if there aren't at least two fields pointing the same table.

Comment: Finished edit to make it even more concise, as requested. The web.php part and DB contents are to show what I want to do, and migrations and models are at bare minimum now.